# Can I use single Azure AD B2C tenant for DEV, STAGE and PROD environments of Django App?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have three basic environments for my Django App. I wanna use Azure AD B2C as an Identity Provider for my app. But I'm a little confused about the followings points

Do we need to create a separate Azure AD B2C tenant for each environment? Like right now I have three environments for my Django app, so I will be creating 3 tenants.

Or if I use a single Azure AD B2C tenant, how will I be differentiating between DEV, STAGE, and PROD users?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don’t need to, but it’s advised to. You can just have different versions of your user flow/custom policy in the same tenant.

Best practises are here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/best-practices#operations

Comment: @JasSure
thanks for the reply. Still have the confusion that how we will be differentiating between users of DEV, STAGE, and PROD. For example, prod_user1 is being registered from the PROD environment. But as we are using a single Azure AD B2C tenant  and all users (DEV, STAGE, PROD) lie in the same place, so that prod_user1 can also sign in on STAGE and DEV environments too. Which is not the required behavior right now.

Comment: You can’t differentiate between those users in the app if they are in the same tenant whilst keeping the b2c user journeys consistent. For that you need seperate tenants.

Comment: Lets say I have a Prod Tenant and a NonProd Tenent... the NonProd Tenant actually right now handles 3 separate nonprod envs, so pretend dev-app1.com, dev-app2.com, dev-app3.com. If you have FB login in AzureB2C, then you have to specify an APP_ID and APP_SECRET in Azure's Identify Providers. That means SUSI (signupsignin) flow is associated with my 1 FB APP's ID/Secret. FB requires you to add a 'Site Url' in the app settings, which I'm not sure is enforced. I hope not, cause i'll put https://www.devapp1.com. Otherwise I'll have to create 3 tenants for 3 different FB apps (for 3 diff urls).

Comment: The site url at FB would actually point to the B2C /authresp endpoint. I think you might be able to add different URLs at FB, but our otherwise, yes, 3 app registrations at FB would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting the way I answered that problem with my requirements, which were:

- The Environment doesn't change anything for the user, it will connect with the same account no matter what
- The claims values are different depending on the Environment
- Avoid multiple tenants if possible

Basically I created a duplicate of user attribute with the format ATTRIBUTENAME_ENVIRONMENT for each possible environment, then duplicated my user flows for each environment, with the same USERFLOWNAME_ENVIRONMENT format, and only selected the correct claims to return in the token. That way, a user that connects with the signupsignin_Production user flow will get a token containing the attributes ending with _Production **only**.

Now in the configuration of my different projects, I just have a configuration variable ENV_SUFFIX that I append to any claim I want to use.